# Mobx-state-tree afterCreate() not synchronous in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to load my application initialState by performing a `load()` function in the `afterCreate()` of my `UserModel`. What I am trying to do is to load an `Authenticated` page instead of a `Login` page if I detect that the `accessToken` is not empty in the `UserStore`.

However the page renders before the `afterCreate()` load function is ran. Which ends up always leading me to the login page.

I followed mainly this [video tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-loading-data-from-the-server) by egghead.io but I am not sure why it's not working in my case.

I'm really stuck and any suggestions is appreciated!

The way I am passing my store is passing in the store using `Provider` in my `App.js`.

**UserModel.js**

```
const User = types
  .model("User", {
    accessToken: types.string
  })
  .actions(self => ({
    afterCreate() {
      self.load();
    },
    load: flow(function*() {
      const localData = yield LocalDB.get("user");
      applySnapshot(self, localData);
    })

  }));
```

The object `LocalDB` is just a wrapper around `AsyncStorage` to help parse the data into json format.

**LocalDB.js**

```
const LocalDB = {    
  get: async function(key) {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);

      try {
        return JSON.parse(value);
      } catch (err) {
        return value;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    }
```

**App.js**

```
let store = UserStore.create({...})
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the issue. I was initializing my store with some default variables at the start like this:

```
let store = UserStore.create({accessToken: ""})
```

Once I updated it to `null` it works fine.

```
let store = UserStore.create({accessToken: null})
```